# PHP $_GET Trouble

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, get

So I am working on a website based off of something called the Hypixel API.

When I use a forum where a user can input a name, I get a response of

```
Player == nullArray ( [0] => Array ( [success] => [cause] => [status] => 204 ) [1] => Array ( [success] => [cause] => [status] => 204 ) )
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

$ign = $_GET['ign'];

include_once('HypixelPHP.php');
$HypixelPHP = new HypixelPHP\HypixelPHP(['api_key' => 'BLOCKED']);
// get a player object using the hypixel api object
$player = $HypixelPHP->getPlayer([\HypixelPHP\KEYS::PLAYER_BY_NAME => '$ign']);
if ($player != null) {
    echo 'View stats for ' . $player->getFormattedName(true, true);
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<h1>GAME STATS</h1>';
    echo '<h3>Mega Walls</h3>';
    echo 'Wins: ' . $player->getStats()->getGameFromID(\HypixelPHP\GameTypes::WALLS3)->getInt('wins');
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Kills: ' . $player->getStats()->getGameFromID(\HypixelPHP\GameTypes::WALLS3)->getInt('kills');
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Final Kills: ' . $player->getStats()->getGameFromID(\HypixelPHP\GameTypes::WALLS3)->getInt('final');
    echo '<br>';

} else {
    echo 'Player == null';
    print_r($HypixelPHP->getUrlErrors());
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
</html>
```

In the form, I did do the name thing correct.

This should be the output:

[image: The output]

Along with some other stuff.

If you guys can help, thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the content of the file HypixelPHP.php? It's referenced in an include, and it'd be helpful to have that source code as well.

Comment: @BrianSchroeter  https://github.com/Plancke/hypixel-php Click on the HypixelPHP folder.

Comment: What output are you getting instead of what you expect?

Comment: You need to put the code that echoes the results inside the `<body>` tag, which has to be inside `<html>`

Comment: @Barmar So how would I do that? Sorry, I am a bit of a noob at $_GET I haven't used it in a while.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `$_GET`, it's just HTML. Move the code that prints the output down on the page.

Comment: Any PHP tutorial should explain how to locate your code in the proper place on the page.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much! It works! I wish I could give you an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are passing the single quoted string '$ign'. This ignored the variable you have set for $ign.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php